# Processing data got throught API

Tags: php, json, api

Been reading for a while about processing data throught API with no luck.
Either it shows full api response OR nothing at all.

API Response looks like that:

```
{"status":"success","data":{"address":"198aMn6ZYAczwrE5NvNTUMyJ5qkfy4g3Hi","balance":8000.00033346,"balance_multisig":0},"code":200,"message":""}
```

And my processing code is:

```
$url = "http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/address/balance/198aMn6ZYAczwrE5NvNTUMyJ5qkfy4g3Hi";
$website = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($website);
printf($result["data"]["balance"]);
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

i need to get **only** the *Balance* part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
printf($result->data->balance);
```

or

```
$result = json_decode($website, true);  // When the second parameter is TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays. 
printf($result["data"]["balance"]);
```

[Reading the manual](http://php.net/json_decode) does help, too.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks, ax. Appreciate it!